# Potion of Transmutation effects for Neutrals/basement members

Tags: werewolv.es

What effect does the Potion of Transmutation have on: Drunk, Graverobber, Vampire (Master), any type of Familiar?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think drunks can be transmuted. But it is possible to transmute a Graverobber into another neutral role. Altho there are not that many neutral, so you can transmute a Graverobber into an Essence Thief, but I think that's about all roles that come to mind. Tanner and special roles like The Ancient One, the Chosen One and Oracle are blocked.